# Laravel - How to query Eloquent relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have this models in Laravel-5.8:

```
class Employee extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'employees';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
                  'id',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'hr_status',      
                  'employee_type_id',
              ];

    public function employeetype()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\EmployeeType','employee_type_id','id');
    }           
}


class EmployeeType extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'employee_types';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
                  'type_name',
                  'is_active',
              ];
}
```

Then I have this Query in Employee controller function:

```
 $unsubmitted = Employee::where('hr_status', 0)->get();
```

How do I include where is_active = 1 from employee_types into the query in Employee:

```
$unsubmitted = Employee::where('hr_status', 0)->get();
```

Comment: so you want all Employees that have `hr_status = 0` and have a relationship to any employeetype that has `is_active = 1`?

Comment: @lagbox - Yes, you are correct

Comment: Side note:  You wrote Laravel 5.8 - this is EOL (End Of Life). You should consider updating to a supported version. See [Laravel Versions](https://laravelversions.com/) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `whereHas` method, querying for the existence of a relationship:

```
Employee::where('hr_status', 0)
    ->whereHas('employeetype', function ($q) {
        $q->where('is_active', 1);
    })->get();
```

[Laravel 5.8 Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) `whereHas`